# How to set listview to center of the screen using Listactivity?

Tags: android, listactivity

I have four items in Listview,but I want to show it in center of screen using Listactivity(programmatically).

Comment: you want to set text in center inside lisview????

Comment: no,whole listview to center of screen using listactivity.

Comment: in your layout file add android:gravity="center" in to listview's perent view.

Comment: try explaining your question with a screen shot..

Comment: no layout!!!! using only listactivity @Dhawal Sodha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `ListActivity` you can write this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And if you want to center the list programmaticaly, you can write in your `ListActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

    final ListView listView = getListView();
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```